# Reference XAML TextBlock to .cs code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock

first of all thanks for taking your time, now
the problem i have is this;
I have different textblocks in my main XAML file, im trying to get their text to use them in a sqlquery from another file(.cs file)

```
    public void FillTable()
    {
        MainWindow l = new MainWindow();

        string sql = "insert into Pacientes (nombre) values ('"+ l.nombre_text.Text +"')";
        var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        l.Close();                

    }
```

However, when i check the Table the result is null, when i check the table the 
"nombre" column is blank

[See sql image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARlkz.jpg)

any clue what im doing wrong?

Comment: Ideally, you would want to use MVVM. You bind each TextBox to a property in the ViewModel, then inside the ViewModel, you will fill the SQL query based on the bound properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a "new MainWindow".  You need to get a reference to your MainWindow or somehow pass in the text to FillTable().

Without seeing more of your code, an exact solution is not probable, but something along these lines might get you unblocked.

```
...
// in MainWindow.cs
FillTable(this);
...

public void FillTable(MainWindow window)
{
    string sql = "insert into Pacientes (nombre) values ('"+ window.nombre_text.Text +"')";
    var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();   
}
```

OR

```
...
FillTable(nombre_text.Text);
...

public void FillTable(string nombre)
{
    string sql = "insert into Pacientes (nombre) values ('"+ nombre +"')";
    var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();   
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear.  Please kindly mark as answer so this issue gets updated properly in SO.